# How to get the number of displayed lines in TMemo?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to get the number of displayed lines in TMemo (this include the lines that was wrapped because WordWrap is set to true). I need this to auto adjust the height of the Tmemo to it's content.

lines.count of course don't care about wrapped lines so i can't use it. strangely TextPosToPos also don't care about wrapped lines so i can't use it too ...

I m under firemonkey and delphi Berlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why using ContentBounds is "not really ideal". Here's how I do it:

```
uses
  FMX.TextLayout, FMX.Graphics;

function MeasureTextHeight(const AFont: TFont; const AText: string): Single;
var
  LLayout: TTextLayout;
begin
  LLayout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  try
    LLayout.BeginUpdate;
    try
      LLayout.WordWrap := False;
      LLayout.Font.Assign(AFont);
      LLayout.Text := AText;
    finally
      LLayout.EndUpdate;
    end;
    Result := LLayout.TextHeight;
  finally
    LLayout.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LTextHeight: Single;
  LLines: Integer;
begin
  LTextHeight := MeasureTextHeight(Memo1.TextSettings.Font, Memo1.Text);
  LLines := Round(Memo1.ContentBounds.Height / LTextHeight);
end;
```

Comment: What about word wrap? This doesn't take the width restriction into consideration. In fact, your code explicitly switches it off, which is the opposite of what OP is looking for.

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm not turning WordWrap off in the memo; check the code again. When I said "here's how I do it", I mean that I am already using it. If it didn't work, I wouldn't have posted it

Comment: thanks Dave! yes it's work like this. however i do in a little different way (i posted my answer later).

Answer (score 3):

Edit after I learned about `ContentsBounds`. My original (and obsolete) answer is still visible in the revisions.

Why do you need the number of displayed lines to adjust the height of the `TMemo`? This resizes the `TMemo` to its content:

```
Memo1.Height := Memo1.ContentBounds.Height + 5; // Small const to allow for rendering margins
```

It also takes word-wrap into consideration.

Comment: thanks tom, i actually do contentbounds / text.size but not really ideal

Comment: thanks tom, yes it's would be easy to play with contentBounds, however i want to limit the height of the memo to 4 lines, this why i need the count of lines

Answer (score -1):

This is the rough way i use to calculate the number of lines an TMemo (styled) under firemonkey :

```
type
  _TStyledMemoProtectedAccess = class(TStyledMemo);

procedure TALStyledMemo.OnApplyStyleLookupImpl(sender: Tobject);
Var I, j, k, l: integer;
begin

  // TALStyledMemo
  //   TStyledMemo
  //      TLayout
  //         TActiveStyleObject
  //            TLayout
  //            TScrollBar
  //            TScrollBar
  //            TLayout
  //               TSmallScrollBar
  //               TSmallScrollBar
  //   TScrollContent
  for I := 0 to controls.Count - 1 do begin
    if (controls[i] is TStyledMemo) then begin // << TStyledMemo
      fStyledMemo := TStyledMemo(controls[i]);
    end;
  end;

end;

function TALStyledMemo.getLineHeight: Single;
begin
  if fStyledMemo <> nil then result := _TStyledMemoProtectedAccess(fStyledMemo).GetLineHeight
  else result := 0;
end;

function TALStyledMemo.getLineCount: integer;
var aLineHeight: Single;
begin
  aLineHeight := getLineHeight;
  if compareValue(aLineHeight, 0, Tepsilon.Position) > 0 then result := round(ContentBounds.Height / aLineHeight)
  else result := 0;
end;
```